# Too large gaps between equations or paragraphs

Tags: spacing

I am using a specific preamble for my thesis, a preamble which I cannot say I completely understand. Sometimes large gaps appear between paragraphs or between text and math equations although there is no visible pattern. Does anyone have any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Have some large formula been moved to the next page such that the pages with large gaps are "short" and thus being stretched?

Comment: you presumably have a default setting of `\flushbottom` in your class which means that tex tries to align the bottom row of each page, if you have uneven material sometimes the only way it can do that is by stretching inter-paragraph space. Try `\raggedbottom`

Comment: @Andrew Swann Indeed I corrected it, thanks! @ David Carlisle Thank you very much \raggedbottom works!